# The chrome browser window becomes active when switching tabs (Selenium, Mac OS)

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

I'm using Chrome browser for testing WebApp.
The chrome browser window becomes active when switching tabs (the window pops up above other applications). This behavior is seen only with chrome, and only on mac os. Has anyone solved a similar problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.